# Does anyone have an insight into ASP.NET WebFormsMVP?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, mvp, webformsmvp

Recently I ran into this open source project ASP.NET [WebformsMVP](http://webformsmvp.com/).

It seems like an alternative to asp.net mvc and also a quick way to introduce testability into an existing webforms applications. (without having to go through the pain of rewriting a bunch of code to make it work for asp.net mvc)

Of couse community support and open-source projects abandonment is always a concern when trying new things, but moving on from those fears, has anyone giving it a serious try at this framework?  If so, can you share some insight into its pros/cons and if it's really worth trying it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

WebformsMVP is included in DotNetNuke now, so we have started using it indirectly as part of custom module development within DNN.

I don't think we're fully utilizing everything the framework is capable of, but have had no problems to date.  The implementation is very clean and simple to implement, and retrofitting existing webforms code is fairly straightforward.  For us the learning curve has been minimal.

We have run into a number of cases where we aren't certain of the "right" way to do things, and have found pretty limited guidance online.  (Try as I might to avoid it, sometimes I just have to poke some stuff into the ViewState.)  But, with it being used by the DNN team, we feel pretty confident that it will not fade away soon, and a growing number of examples should appear online.

Of course I encourage its use, even if only for the selfish reason of wanting to see the community grow.

Comment: Hi Jim,
It's good to know that someone big like DNN is using webFormsMVP.  I would be interested to hear your thoughts about it as you implement your custom module.

Comment: Here is a demo DotNetNuke module I've built out using WebFormsMVP. https://github.com/irobinson/BeerCollectionMVP